# HTML opacity attribute vs CSS opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know of two different ways of setting opacity in HTML:

`<div opacity="0.5"></div>` and

`<div style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>`

I also know how to set both of those in JavaScript:

`div.setAttribute("opacity", 0.5);` and

`div.style.opacity = 0.5`

Are there any major differences between those two methods? Should I prefer one over the other? (I guess I should at least be consistent)

Comment: You actually know only one way of setting opacity in HTML - the first one you posted has zero effect in every major browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only `opacity` *attribute* I am aware of is [for use with SVGs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/opacity):

> Example Elements
>
> The following elements can use the opacity attribute
>
> [Graphics elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element#Graphics) [and]
>   `<a>` `<defs>` 
>   `<glyph>` 
>   `<g>` 
>   `<marker>` 
>   `<missing-glyph>`
>   `<pattern>` 
>   `<svg>` 
>   `<switch>` 
>   `<symbol>`

Your `<div opacity="0.5"></div>` doesn't work in HTML and therefore, to style HTML elements, opacity should be controlled with CSS.

Comment: Oh you're right, I was using it only in JS and on SVG so I didn't think about that.

Answer (score -1):

CSS is always faster than Javascript. If your are able to do anything with CSS then why waste time with Javascript.

CSS precedence rules say inline and html attribute  are given higher order then External or Embedded CSS. However inline CSS is not good practice, until it is required in your project for certain reason

**Proper CSS opacity code:**

```
img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/

```
img {
  /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
  /* ...but not required as filter works too */
  /* should come BEFORE filter */
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // IE8

  /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
  /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); // IE 5-7

  /* Modern Browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't see you address the question. The question asks about using (a) an attribute of the div itself **vs** (b) an attribute of a css style applied to the element. Javascript is not relevant here, since each method may be employed without its use.

Comment: Mike, all answers are welcome as they mean someone is trying to help another for free. However, your particular answer doesn't answer the question at all. I haven't downvoted you, I feel there's no need to. It's a simple question, opacity in CSS or HTML attribute, not Javascript, inline styling or anything else

Comment: Looks better, but I still dont see it addressing the question at hand. It really is very simple. Which is the better way of altering an element's opacity? Is it with the opacity attribute of the element or is it with the opacity attribute of a css rule applied to the element. Dont care about JS, don't care about internal/external CSS. Just html attribute VS css attribute. You'll have to take up the issue of the downvote with whomever left it. Anyway, the issue is moot - misterManSam has just reminded us of what we should have remembered. There is no `opacity` attribute except in SVG.