# canvas opacity not showing background behind

Tags: css, canvas

So I am programming a little game in html css and javascript. I use a canvas for the graphics. Now I want to add a background image to the page, and want the canvas to be a little transparent so you can see the background. For that I used the opacitiy property in css. But no matter what value I use, the background isn't showing up. The canvas is getting like less saturated but. So I know the property is working. But the background behind the canvas is just not rendering. I browsed the internet for a solution but I couldn't fine any.

Here is the css code:

```
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And I changed the canvas propertys inline html:

```
<canvas id="pong_singleplayer_canvas" height="640" width="960" style="opacity: 0.7;"></canvas>
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Add [mcve] to your question pls

Comment: I modified your example to a snippet and dont see the described behavior. May be your image just dont load? Or this bug is browser specific? Anyway, as you see - example is not reproducible. Clarify the question

Comment: Ok the snipet is working but if you check this link you will see it doesnt' work either on my browser or on my host: http://gymgames.ch/games/pong/pong_singleplayer/pong.singleplayer.v2.html The image is just for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set non-transparent backgound (`#eee`) to your canvas element.
Solution is set background color with transparency. And I remove `opacity` option from canvas element, now background of canvas is transparent but game elements is not:

```js
const ctx = pong_singleplayer_canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(200,50,200,100);
```

```css
canvas {
    background: rgba(238, 238, 238, .7);
    display: block;
    padding: 10;
    margin: 0 auto;
}



body {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="pong_singleplayer_canvas" height="200" width="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: good call. I should have thought of that thx

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 This issue more simple than i think. 
`opacity` is just not html attribute (except SVG elements), it is CSS option only) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511962/html-opacity-attribute-vs-css-opacity